# Need help with sorting NSMutableArray with custom objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

sorry to bother you with this question, but after hours of googleing and browsing here, I still cannot figure out, what's the problem.

The thing is, I create a NSMutableArray with custom objects of type 'SearchResult'.
The SearchResult class is still pretty basic:

```
@interface SearchResult : NSObject {

    NSString *_id;
    NSString *_title;
    NSNumber *_year;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *id;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *year;

@end
```

here is the code, where the (bad) magic happens:

```
if (self.sResults == nil) {
    self.sResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
else if ([self.sResults count] > 0){
    [self.sResults removeAllObjects];
}
//JsonConverter uses JsonTouchKit for parsing a json string
JsonConverter *_converter = [[JsonConverter alloc] init];
NSDictionary *parsedResults = [_converter getParsedObjectFromData:results];

for (NSDictionary *movieObj in [parsedResults objectForKey:@"results"]) {
    SearchResult *movie = [_converter newSearchResultObjectFromSearchJsonObject:movieObj];
    [self.sResults addObject:movie];
}
[_converter release];
//sort the results
NSSortDescriptor *desc = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"year" ascending:NO] autorelease];

NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:desc];
[self.sResults sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];  //<-- HERE!!!
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

The thing is, if I get only a few results, e.g. 3, everything is fine and the array is sorted correctly. BUT as soon as I get some more results, e.g. 18, the app crashes on the marked line with a 'SIGABRT' and the below stack.
If I inspect the given adress "0x5c31470" with my little knowledge of gdb commands I get the following:

```
po 0x5c31470 -> 2004 //yes, thats the year it should use for sorting
whatis 0x5c31470 -> type = int
```

Stack track:

> 2011-09-13 12:30:10.352 VideoCatalogue[1294:207] -[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c31470
>
> 2011-09-13 12:30:10.353 VideoCatalogue[1294:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c31470'

Has anyone any idea, how I can solve this? Thank very much!

Comment: The error messages are telling you that you're trying to sort an element that doesn't respond to "length".  In particular, you appear to have an NSNumber element in your array.

Comment: Yes, that's the intention. The array should be sorted on an attribute of type NSNumber, which is the 'year' of the SearchResult class. But that doesn't explain, why it's working on short Arrays correctly.

Comment: Your short array doesn't have an NSNumber in it.

Comment: Hint: Do an `NSLog(@"%@", [self.sResults description]);` ahead of the sort, to see what you're sorting.

Comment: And, as suggested below, use `sortedArrayUsingFunction` -- it's much easier to understand what you're doing with that, and to handle oddball cases.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the hint and suggestions! I will try all this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: ok, the thing was that one of the results didn't have a years value. So the JsonParser assigned a NSString instead of a NSNumber. So using sortUsingFunction and writing my own comparer did the trick of noticing that a value was missing (which actually should not happen -> error in backend). Thanks Daniel and user509446!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this approach:[NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)
Look for the explanation of: `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:`